# JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation

Tags: c#

When i run the test cases i got follwing error *JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation* when i run this line 
`actual = StoreHealth_Accessor.lookupRuleManagerandFilterRawdata(rawdt, dtRuleManagerTable, ref listobj, distinctredc, idevicegroupcount, storeID);` i get error so how to resolve it? any idea.

```
public void lookupRuleManagerandFilterRawdataTest4()
    {

        DataTable rawdt = new DataTable(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        rawdt.Columns.Add("AssetTag", typeof(string));
        rawdt.Columns.Add("Service_ID", typeof(string));
        rawdt.Columns.Add("ModelName", typeof(string));
        rawdt.Columns.Add("Store_ID", typeof(string));
        rawdt.Columns.Add("Last_Time_State_Change", typeof(DateTime));
        rawdt.Columns.Add("Severity", typeof(int));
        rawdt.Columns.Add("Message_Text", typeof(string));
        rawdt.Columns.Add("Retailer_ID", typeof(string));
        rawdt.Columns.Add("Device_Group_Info", typeof(string));
        DataRow drTable1 = rawdt.NewRow();

        drTable1["AssetTag"] = "CPU-00000000000US1941K017";
        drTable1["Service_ID"] = "Citizen DS40 - Paper End / Out of Paper";
        drTable1["ModelName"] = "HP IS1700 Input Station";
        drTable1["Store_ID"] = "CIN00001";
        drTable1["Last_Time_State_Change"] = "7/20/2012 4:10:34 AM";
        drTable1["Severity"] = 128;
        drTable1["Retailer_ID"] = "CIN";
        drTable1["Device_Group_Info"] = "Input Station";
        drTable1["Message_Text"] = "Citizen DS40 - Paper End / Out of Paper";



        //DataTable dtRuleManagerTable = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value

        DataTable dtRuleManagerTable = new DataTable();
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("RuleID", typeof(string));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("Drive_Store_Status", typeof(int));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("Service_ID", typeof(string));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("Device_Group_Name", typeof(string));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("AssetTag", typeof(string));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("Severity", typeof(int));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("ModelName", typeof(string));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("Store_ID", typeof(string));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("Last_Time_State_Change", typeof(DateTime));

        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("Message_Text", typeof(string));
        dtRuleManagerTable.Columns.Add("Retailer_ID", typeof(string));


        DataRow drTable = dtRuleManagerTable.NewRow();


        drTable["AssetTag"] = "CPU-00000000000US1941K017";
        drTable["Service_ID"] = "Citizen DS40 - Paper End / Out of Paper";
        drTable["ModelName"] = "HP IS1700 Input Station";
        drTable["Store_ID"] = "CIN00001";
        drTable["Last_Time_State_Change"] = "7/20/2012 4:10:34 AM";
        drTable["Severity"] = 128;
        drTable["Retailer_ID"] = "CIN";

        drTable["Message_Text"] = "Citizen DS40 - Paper End / Out of Paper";

        drTable["RuleID"] = "101A";
        drTable["Drive_Store_Status"] = 1;

        drTable["Device_Group_Name"] = "Input Station ";
        List<DeviceGroupCountDetailsforstore_Accessor> listobj = new List<DeviceGroupCountDetailsforstore_Accessor>(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        DeviceGroupCountDetailsforstore_Accessor devgrpcountobj = new DeviceGroupCountDetailsforstore_Accessor();

         Hashtable severitynum = new Hashtable();
         Hashtable hsevry = new Hashtable();
        hsevry.Add("101A",1);
        devgrpcountobj.severitynum.Add("Input Station", hsevry);


        listobj.Add(devgrpcountobj);
        //devgrpcountobj.severitynum;
       // DeviceGroupCountDetailsforstore_Accessor.AttachShadow(listobj);
        //listobj.Add("input station");

        List<string> distinctredc = new List<string>{"Input Station","Routers"}; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int idevicegroupcount = 2; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string storeID = "CIN00001"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        bool expected = true; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        bool actual;
        actual = StoreHealth_Accessor.lookupRuleManagerandFilterRawdata(rawdt, dtRuleManagerTable, ref listobj, distinctredc, idevicegroupcount, storeID);


        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
    }
```

Comment: What is `StoreHealth_Accessor.lookupRuleManagerandFilterRawdata` ?

Comment: This type of error is usually associated with IL-level programming, perhaps via an IoC/DI tool, or an ORM. So: what tools are you using here? Where did the failing method failing one from, and what does it do?

Comment: Try running PEVerify on your assembly http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd.aspx it may help to point you in the right direction

Comment: It is object used to access the methods of the class this is error thrown while doing MS testing. so how to resolve the issue